# Whose Head is this?

Tags: minifigure-identification

I've found this kind of cool looking minifigure:

[image: cool looking minifigure]

Apologizes for the poor picture. :(

But after some research, I think I have determined that this *body* would have come from set [6584 - Extreme team challenge](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/6584-1).

The thing is I don't think the head is right for the body:

[image: This head is different]

So now I have no idea as to what set this head came from.

Where did this head come from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the "Moustache Red, Headset, Red Eyebrows Pattern" minifigure head:

[image: the head]

It appeared in two different minifigures.

The [Explorien Chief](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=sp009) minifigure featured in [three sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=sp009&in=S) from the Explorien theme:

[image: Explorien guy]

And ["Aquaraider 1 with hook"](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?M=aqu004) featured in [two sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=aqu004&in=S) from the Aquazone theme:

[image: Aquazone guy]

Comment: Thanks for identifying it. I'm again having flashbacks of the Lego Racers game going through my head when I see these Exploration sets.

Comment: After looking around on my own, I found that this head was used in _two_ different [types of minifigures](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpb057&in=M). I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for editing it.  I was constrained by my (former) noob status and couldn't post pictures.

Comment: Well, after this you're a n00b no more! Congratulations :)